# Azure webjobs failed [Access is denied]

Tags: c#, console-application, gmail-api, azure-webjobs

I created a console application to read gmail inbox.I need my console app to read emails every 15 minutes.So i published the console app as webjobs with runmode : "On demand" and published the app using azure services (web apps).

But my webjobs doesn't seem to run and there is no option to schedule a webjob when i select publish as azure webjobs.

As soon as i publish i get this error in visual studio :

```
'ICICIEmailParser.sstageEntities-Web.config Connection String' argument cannot be null or empty
```

The webjob has no scheduled time so i manually ran the webjob from azure portal and when viewed log i see below error

> [01/03/2017 06:48:38 > 7e6d88: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:38 > 7e6d88: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: Job file 'ICICIEmailParser.application' timestamp differs between source and working directories.
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:39 > 7e6d88: SYS INFO] Run script 'ICICIEmailParser.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:39 > 7e6d88: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ] 
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__6.MoveNext()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at GmailQuickstart.Program.d__3.MoveNext()
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: ERR ]    at GmailQuickstart.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
>   [01/03/2017 06:48:40 > 7e6d88: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

Things i have done :

I have a client-secret.json file of google oauth.
I have added google secret and client id in my azure web app authentication/authorization
I set javascript origin and redirect uri in google developer console

This is my main method :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task.WaitAll(GetEmail());


    }
static async Task GetEmail() {
//my c# code to read gmail inbox...

}
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure WebJob fails on exit code 532462766](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648501/azure-webjob-fails-on-exit-code-532462766)

Comment: Sounds like you're asking two unrelated questions: one related to how to do scheduling, and the other related to an error you get when running the WebJobs. Please simplify the question to only cover one thing. I assume the runtime issue is your primary question.

Answer (score 0):

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied

According to your description, I assumed that you have followed [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) to create your .NET console application that makes requests to the Gmail API. I followed the above tutorial and deployed it as Azure WebJobs, then I could reproduce this error. When running your command-line application (WebJob) on Azure, it would prompt you to authorize access and open a new window or tab in the default browser of the web server. However Azure WebJobs work as a background task under behind the website hosted on Azure for doing regular jobs and batch work, the end-users couldn't Interact with your WebJob to finish the authorization.

> But my webjobs doesn't seem to run and there is no option to schedule a webjob when i select publish as azure webjobs.

As I known, you could leverage the following approaches to schedule your WebJob:

- Use `TimerTrigger` from [Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions)
- Use [Azure Scheduler job](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html) to trigger your WebJob with some schedule
- Schedule Azure WebJobs with [cron expressions](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html)

> I have added google secret and client id in my azure web app authentication/authorization I set javascript origin and redirect uri in google developer console

Per my understanding, you are trying to authenticate/authorize your web app with Google Account and schedule the WebJob to read messages from Gmail with the logged UserCredential. As I known, WebJobs couldn't directly communicate with your web app, I assumed that you need to store the logged UserCredential and schedule your webjob to retrieve the UserCredential to read messages from Gmail API.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.I somehow managed to run the webjob.Here is what i have done.I used server to server oauth of gmail api so that no user interaction is required.They provided me with a private key which i used to get a google token then read the email.When deploying i just deployed the release folder in my remote computer (not azure).From the remote computer when i run my exe my program ran successfully.Hope this helps someone who is trying to achieve the same.

Comment: Could you please post your solution with more details and mark it as an answer for other community who could encounter the similar issue?