# Azure WebJob fail to start

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have created an Azure WebJob in Visual Studio 2015 and deployed it to Azure.

When trying to run the WebJob I get this error:

```
[03/12/2017 22:47:46 > 070c62: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: ERR ] 
[03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: ERR ]    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.EntryPoint.Main()
[03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
[03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

I have tried to search for this error but can't find anything related to this. I don't know if this is an problem in my WebJob code or the configuration of the WebJob in Azure.

Does anyone have some ideas or pointers of where the problem lies?

Comment: You can start with [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues) to help isolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   [03/12/2017 22:47:47 > 070c62: ERR ]    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.EntryPoint.Main()

Firstly, as David Ebbo said,  please try to run the same logic outside of the Azure Web App sandbox, and check if it works fine.

Besides, as far as I know, if the WebJobs project missed the referenced assemblies or files, we would get similar issue as yours. For example, my console application referenced Newtonsoft.Json, but I do not include this file when I deploy console app as WebJobs to Azure, I get below error.

[image]

The ConsoleApplication13.Program.Main() is entry point of my console application, please check your project to make sure you did not miss some assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the same problem by changing the `Main()` method slightly.
It is important to leave the following lines at the top of the `Main()`.

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

if (config.IsDevelopment)
{
    config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
}
config.Queues.BatchSize = 2; //Number of messages to dequeue at the same time.
config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 5; //Max retries before move the messate to the poison.
config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //Pooling request to the queue.
config.NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver(); //Dynamic queue name resolver.

JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
```

After that I searched all the "Console.Writeline()" that I wrote in all the source code and deleted them, because I was thinking that it belonged to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync dll.

After that I deleted all the webjobs configured at the webApp in the portal and published again.

Voilá all the WebJobs were running again.

Now I wrote again the "console.WriteLine" and every continues running well. So I think that the important thing is to have the JobHostconfiguration at the top most of the Main:

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

if (config.IsDevelopment)
{
    config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
}
config.Queues.BatchSize = 2; //Number of messages to dequeue at the same time.
config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 5; //Max retries before move the messate to the poison.
config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //Pooling request to the queue.
config.NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver(); //Dynamic queue name resolver.

JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the web job with error from azure.

Then verify whether Solution configuration is in "Release" mode.
[image]

Finally, deploy again.

*PS: Hope the web job runs without any errors from local !*