# Why webjob is failing with exit code 532462766?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

This is the error stated by the webjob console. Earlier the same code was running fine at least it was making a logging in application insight. This is the error:

```
[06/29/2022 08:14:21 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[06/29/2022 08:14:25 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Run script 'ArchiveOldSMBFiles.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[06/29/2022 08:14:25 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[06/29/2022 08:14:26 > fa1ef8: ERR ] 
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ArchiveOldSMBFiles.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element. (D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\webjob7\awufcgqk.dxj\Debug\ArchiveOldSMBFiles.exe.config line 38)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InitializeSockets()
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.AddressChangeListener.StartHelper(NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler caller, Boolean captureContext, StartIPOptions startIPOptions)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.Network.AddAddressChangedEventHandler(NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler handler) in /_/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/Implementation/Network.cs:line 12
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.TransmissionPolicy.NetworkAvailabilityTransmissionPolicy.SubscribeToNetworkAddressChangedEvents() in /_/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/Implementation/TransmissionPolicy/NetworkAvailabilityTransmissionPolicy.cs:line 36
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.TransmissionPolicy.NetworkAvailabilityTransmissionPolicy.Initialize(Transmitter transmitter) in /_/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/Implementation/TransmissionPolicy/NetworkAvailabilityTransmissionPolicy.cs:line 19
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.TransmissionPolicy.TransmissionPolicyCollection.Initialize(Transmitter transmitter) in /_/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/Implementation/TransmissionPolicy/TransmissionPolicyCollection.cs:line 49
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.Transmitter..ctor(TransmissionSender sender, TransmissionBuffer transmissionBuffer, TransmissionStorage storage, TransmissionPolicyCollection policies, BackoffLogicManager backoffLogicManager) in /_/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/Implementation/Transmitter.cs:line 57
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel..ctor(INetwork network, IApplicationLifecycle applicationLifecycle) in /_/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/ServerTelemetryChannel.cs:line 52
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel..ctor() in /_/BASE/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/ServerTelemetryChannel.cs:line 41
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at ArchiveOldSMBFiles.Program..cctor() in D:\Projects\ArchiveOldSMBFiles\Program.cs:line 30
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: ERR ]    at ArchiveOldSMBFiles.Program.Main(String[] args)
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[06/29/2022 08:14:27 > fa1ef8: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

My code:

```
class Program
    {
        static IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace))
        .AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel())
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]);

        static IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        static ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        static TelemetryClient telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var _storageConn = ConfigurationManager
                .AppSettings["PaperCaptureStorageConnectionString"];
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;
               
                JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
                config.StorageConnectionString = _storageConn;
              
                var host = new JobHost(config);
                Task callTask = host.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(Program.ProcessMethod)));

                callTask.Wait();
                host.RunAndBlock();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static void ProcessMethod()
        {
            using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("ArchiveOldSMBFiles1233"))
            {
                logger.LogInformation("-ArchiveOldSMBFiles.Main Execution Started");
                var totalDeletedFiles = 0;
                try
                {
                    string jsonTemplate = string.Empty;
                    string fileShareName = string.Empty;
                    Console.WriteLine("Before unity of work");
                    using (var unitOfWork = new DataConnector().UnitOfWork)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("After unity of work");
                        jsonTemplate = ConfigurationService.GetConfigValueByConfigCode(
                            BusinessLogic.Helper.Constants.ConfigType.AzureConstantValues
                            , BusinessLogic.Helper.Constants.ConfigCode.SMBRemoveOldFile, unitOfWork);

                        Console.WriteLine("This is your json: " + jsonTemplate);                       
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("After Catch");
                    Console.WriteLine("Crash: "+ ex.ToString());
                    logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("After finally");
                    telemetryClient.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I have fixed the Azure SQL connection issue which was caused by the wrong Azure connection string.
I am uploading my webjob by zipping Debug folder and uploading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the error **`Job failed due to exit code -532462766`**,
please check the following:

- This error usually occurs when the **`config`** file is broken.
- After installing the Application Insights try comparing the configuration files.
- Please check whether you have **`web.config`** file. If not,  try creating **`web.config`** in console app similar to **`app.config`** and republish [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648501/azure-webjob-fails-on-exit-code-532462766#:%7E:text=In%20most%20cases%20the%20application,client%20PC%20and%20not%20server.) by **Lucas Huet-Hudson**.
- Try copying the the *programname*.exe.config file along with the exe as answered by **Nasir Razzaq** in the above thread.
- Try to disable the dashboard logging as suggested by **NicolajHedeager** in this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1085#issuecomment-307732832) Blog.

If the issue still persists, raise [**Azure Support Ticket**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/) to know the root cause of the issue.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Turning a console app into a long-running Azure WebJob – Sander van de Velde (wordpress.com) by **Sander van de Velde**](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/turning-a-console-app-into-a-long-running-azure-webjob/)

[Azure WebJob fails with exit code 532462766 (microsoft.com) by **Anastasia Black**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a77b642-bf8b-49e8-9359-711ce34ca31e/azure-webjob-fails-with-exit-code-532462766?forum=ApplicationInsights)